# How should I interpret this problem in Ash's *Probability and Measure Theory*?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, problem-solving

Problem 9a in *Probability and Measure theory* by Ash and Doléans-Dade reads:

> Let $\mathscr C$ be an arbitrary class of subsets of $\Omega$, and let
> $\mathscr G$ be the collection of all finite unions $\bigcup_{i=1}^n
> A_i$, $n = 1, 2, \dotsc$, where each $A_i$ is a finite intersection
> $\bigcap_{j=1}^r B_{ij}$, with $B_{ij}$ or its complement a set in
> $\mathscr C$. Show that $\mathscr G$ is the minimal field (not
> $\sigma$-field) over $\mathscr C$.

Should I interpret $r$ as being a fixed parameter in this problem? The wording makes me think that the sets $A_i$ are actually supposed to be *arbitrary* finite intersections,
$$
A_i = \bigcap_{j=1}^{r_i} B_{ij}, \quad r_i \in \mathbb \{0, 1, 2, \dotsc\},
$$
with $B_{ij}$ or its complement in $\mathscr C$. Maybe it will become clear while working on the problem, but I would still appreciate your input.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It could end up being the case that $r$ can be fixed (not sure on this). The point of this exercise is really that a minimal field admits an explicit constructive representation. This is in stark contrast to $\sigma$ fields, which generally do not.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will at the very least start with this interpretation, and then maybe think about other possibilities later.